# django-viewflow with celery: licensing question

Tags: django-viewflow

I'm using django-viewflow for a web app.

I need to understand if viewflow (nonpro) StartSignal can be started from a celery task, or this feature already requires a pro-license.
This doubt arises from the viewflow documentation since it states that the celery integration available in the pro software is about the celery flow-node.

Comment: Using flow.StartSignal does not require pro license

Comment: Even if that (custom) signal comes from a celery task?

Comment: Viewflow open source licensed under AGPL license with exception paragraph, that give few additional permission. There is no way to restrict signal code usage in the AGPL